# How to add a string with spaces at the end of command output

Tags: sed, string, whitespace

I want to add a string with spaces at the end of each line of the output of `ls` command.

```
#!/bin/sh
STRING_WITH_SPACES="this should be at the end of output"
ls -lh | sed 's|$| '$STRING_WITH_SPACES'|'
```

The script above works fine when `$STRING_WITH_SPACES` has no spaces:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  4 14:55 testfile thisshouldbeattheend
```

However when there are spaces in `$STRING_WITH_SPACES` sed complains:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
STRING_WITH_SPACES="a string with spaces"
ls -l | sed "s/$/ $STRING_WITH_SPACES/"
```

Answer (score 3):

Please [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). There is no reason to and it complicates things. A safer way to write your script would be

```
#!/bin/sh
STRING_WITH_SPACES="this should be at the end of output"
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -ls | sed "s/$/ $STRING_WITH_SPACES/"
```

Comment: Please, don't get paranoid. Nobody parse output of `ls` here, but add some info of each line. Don't use `ls` at all, it's evil :-D

Comment: My example was a minimal test case. My initial intention was to print contents of several directories which were specfied in a file, but only print filename, filesize and location(which was the STRING_WITH_SPACES).

Comment: @fazie I know, which is why I upvoted your answer. I just thought the warning was worth mentioning since there are many problems with parsing `ls`.